# Using start and end event logs to create a table/view containing spans between the times of each log

Tags: postgresql

To be specific, I have an event table that logs when a user joins or leaves a team.  It looks something like the following:

```
-------------------------------------
| user | event  | team | timestamp |
-------------------------------------
| A    | joined | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| B    | joined | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| C    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| C    | joined | 2    | 2016-1-1  |
| A    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-2  |
| A    | joined | 2    | 2016-1-2  |
| B    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-3  |
| A    | left   | 2    | 2016-1-3  |
-------------------------------------
```

I need to restructure this in a view to look something like the following

```
--------------------------------------
| user | team | joined    | left     |
--------------------------------------
| A    | 1    | 2016-1-1  | 2016-1-2 |
| A    | 2    | 2016-1-2  | 2016-1-3 |
| B    | 1    | 2016-1-1  | 2016-1-3 |
| C    | 1    | null      | 2016-1-1 |
| C    | 2    | 2016-1-1  | null     |
--------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

For more detail, I'm attempting to do this in Amazon Redshift (PostgreSQL)